Horror movie about people getting a radio message they don’t understand
Looking for a sci-fi/horror movie from 1970’s or early 80’s. The only thing I can remember is a group of people keep getting a radio message that they don’t understand that turns out being a warning from the future.
I remember it being horror- something the message was trying to tell them.

Trope of Ominous Message From The Future although none of the four film entries seem to fit.

Hmm... do you recall if it turned out that the message was from them, maybe with it ending with them attempting to send the message and instead getting the garbled mess that they heard earlier on?

What were the horror elements in this film?

Event Horizon 1997? Its a stretch but the crew of the salvage ship finds a distorted message which they think is an SOS call. By the end of the movie, they finally decrypt the message. It is not "Save us." it is closer to "We are beyond saving, do not attempt to save us. Save your souls, this is hell."

Not event horizon - I remember is being terrestrial - like a message appearing outside an abandoned house

Can you rule out Prince of Darkness (1987)? It has something similar to what you've described, but the description is so thin that I'm not confident that it's what you're looking for.

This is John Carpenter's Prince of Darkness (1987), a religious horror film with a sci-fi twist.

A group of graduate students and scientists uncover an ancient canister in an abandoned church, but when they open the container, they inadvertently unleash a strange liquid and an evil force on all humanity.

The main cast are a priest, a physics professor, and some other scientists and students who uncover an ancient secret whilst gathered in a church in Los Angeles.


Prince of Darkness (1987)

Whenever these people sleep during the course of the film, they each have the same, recurring dream involving a shadowy figure emerging from the entrance of the church, with a voiceover telling them that this is not a dream, but rather a transmission from the year 1999, sent with the hope of altering the events being shown.



They initially think they're just dreaming, but after realising that they're all having the same dream, they begin to speculate that perhaps it is actually a message from the future, and how such a message could theoretically be sent.

HOWARD: What if these dreams, premonitions, omens... What if they're really... visual messages sent by other human beings? Photographs. Video signals.
LOMAX: From where?
CATHERINE: The future. Anything traveling faster than the speed of light would appear to be going backward in time.
BRIAN: A future scientist calculates the exact spot that the Earth occupied in space in the past, given trajectory and speed. He then beams a tachyon signal at that spot, transmitting video information backwards through time.
CATHERINE: For us to receive as electrical impulses, neural stimulus.
WALTER: Man, oh, man.
PAUL: For what purpose?
BRIAN: Could be a warning. To show us what's going to happen.
A sort of... remote camera view of the future, so that we can change it.
Prince of Darkness (1987)

